# Get-ChildItem ForEach-Object vs foreach issue

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

So basically I am iterating through a directory recursively but it contains huge number of files.

Two methods I have but I have a problem with each.

**1st Method ( ForEach-Object) :**

```
$Path = "d:\test\"
$writer =  [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("d:\result.csv")
$writer.WriteLine('"File Name","Creation Time","Directory"')
$folders = Get-ChildItem $Path -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -Recurse -File |

ForEach-Object {    
        
        $writer.WriteLine(('"{0}","{1}","{2}"' -f $_.Name, $_.CreationTime, $_.Directory))
        # Note: I have here up to 15 variables to write
}
```

Problem with this is that it takes more than 15 minutes to finish.

**2nd Method (foreach) :**

```
foreach ($file in $folders) {   
        
        $writer.WriteLine(('"{0}","{1}","{2}"' -f $file.Name, $file.CreationTime, $file.Directory))

}
```

I have done some research and it seems that foreach is faster because it puts them all in memory before processing but the problem with this is that I am getting an Out of Memory exception due to the number of files

*Note: The above code is a simple form of what I am using, I am actually splitting the output to a number of csv files according to a specific number of rows - but I don't believe it has to do anything with my issue.*
Any suggestion to either speed up the 1st method or solve the memory issue of the 2nd?

Comment: Are you able to use PowerShell 7? If so, the ForEach-Object -Parallel option might help, though without a rough idea for how many files you're working with here it's hard to know for sure. Can you define what huge means here?

Comment: @Persistent13 millions of files, thanks for the comment I have ver 5 I will check if can update that and check the Parallel option

Comment: @Persistent13 I upgraded to PS 7 , however I am getting error : "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." on the $writer.WriteLine function. Any idea?

Comment: Unrelated to other comments and it is a while since I worked with StreamWriter but I think you want to flush it from time to time so it get written to the files. If you add a mod (%) statement in your foreach so that each 10000 elements you call flush, it will purge the streamwriter memory to the file and possibly avoid the out of memory exception.

Comment: If you have some c# knowledge, using Add-Type and / or compliling a small dll that you'd invoke through PS might save you a ludicrous amount of time for that kind of work. I once had a lot of data to parse and save to CSV and I got from 60 seconds to 0.5 seconds by compiling a on-the-side c# tiny librarry containing the processing logic.

Answer (score 0):

As for ...

[So basically I am iterating through a directory recursively but it contains a huge number of files.]'

This is what PowerShell jobs are for in v5...

> [about_Jobs - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs)
>
> [Background Jobs - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20v5%20background%20jobs&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20v5%20background%20jobs&sc=1-29&sk=&cvid=27093A1E8B754A0EB58A70A28BD93E91)

... or as noted the PSv7 -Parallel approach. Installing PSv7 does not upgrade Windows Powershell v5. They are side by side installs by design. Completely different environment paths.

Either way, you're doing a recursive search and you say millions of files, so, any concept of this being fast is moot. Well, fast is relative to the person needing the performance metric. Directories, have to be discovered, files have to be enumerated, if the files are protected, you have another issue, if you have files with long file names you can have issues.

> [Parallel Processing with jobs in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/parallel-processing-with-jobs-in-powershell)
>
> [Parallel Processing in PowerShell](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/parallel-processing-in-powershell)
>
> Here are three tasks that all can run concurrently:

```
$start = Get-Date

# get all hotfixes
$task1 = { Get-Hotfix }

# get all scripts in your profile
$task2 = { Get-Service | Where-Object Status -eq Running }

# parse log file
$task3 = { Get-Content -Path $env:windir\windowsupdate.log | Where-Object { $_ -like '*successfully installed*' } }

# run 2 tasks in the background, and 1 in the foreground task
$job1 =  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $task1 
$job2 =  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $task2 
$result3 = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $task3

# wait for the remaining tasks to complete (if not done yet)
$null = Wait-Job -Job $job1, $job2

# now they are done, get the results
$result1 = Receive-Job -Job $job1
$result2 = Receive-Job -Job $job2

# discard the jobs
Remove-Job -Job $job1, $job2

$end = Get-Date
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason `-Parallel` is giving you trouble is scoping.  I haven't used it much but you generally have to reference external variables with the `$Using:` scope modifier.  However, there were complications referencing like `$Using:Writer...`, It wouldn't allow expressions.

I was able to get some code samples working with `ForEach-Obejct -Parallel`, however they were actually 5x slower than your original `ForEach-Object` based code. So, I shelved that idea for now.

Given the memory concern I looked for a way to simply stream this a little faster and I think I came up with something.

```
$Path = "c:\temp2\"
$Path = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$Path

$writer =  [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new("c:\temp\result.csv")
$writer.WriteLine('"File Name","Creation Time","Directory"')

$Path.GetFiles( '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories ) |
ForEach-Object{ $Writer.WriteLine( ('"{0}","{1}","{2}"' -f $_.Name, $_.CreationTime, $_.Directory) ) }  

$Writer.Close()
```

When I compared the `.GetFiles()` method to `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File`. it was 4 - 5x faster. My last measure meant was 43ms compared to 184, so ~4.28x faster.  However, when I incorporated it with the rest of the code it was ~2 - 2.4x faster.

In PowerShell 7.1 114ms versus 271 and PoSh 5.1 it was 216ms versus 446.

Note: I tested several times with similar results, these are just the last samples.

Note: Obviously, and in the interests of time, I only tested on a much smaller tree, and only on my local machine.  I can't be certain this approach side-steps the memory issues as `.Get-Files()` may front load before sending data down the pipe.  also can't be certain the performance will hold up on a network share, which I presume is your use case.

**Important:** Regardless of what you do it would seem PowerShell 7.1 is significantly faster at this task.  7.1 performed significantly better at both approaches.

Last point: I did entertain possibly writing our own recursion. However, if I understand how recursion works, it would have simply piled up commands on the stack.  I can't be certain without testing on a similarly large tree, but that struck me as risking the same memory issues, so I didn't make any such attempt.

When I get back on my work environment I'll keep testing / experimenting ...

Comment: Thanks ! I will test this and get back to you. Would you mind share the -Parallel code that you made it work? It seems I cannot use streamwriter to write new lines with -Parallel parameter.

Answer (score 0):

And if you use this command, how is the time?

```
$Path = "d:\test\"
Get-ChildItem $Path -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -Recurse -File | 
        select Name, CreationTime, Directory |  
                export-csv "d:\result.csv" -del ',' -NoType
```

Comment: I am not using the export-csv because I am splitting the output to multiple Csv files.

Comment: I modified this to limit number of rows/csv , I will check speed and get back to u, but I believe streamwriter should be faster than the export-csv as per other posts